# What library to use so that user can manually classify the given images from the gallery?

Tags: python, python-imaging-library, user-input, user-interaction

I want to create a python program that asks user to put the images in particular category. For example there are 10 categories (say 1 to 10). The program will display the image gallery and user will manually put the image in one of the 10 categories. After all the images are classified, it creates the database of image with the images classified in all these 10 categories. SO next time the database is loaded, it comes with the classified categories.

For example, there are folder containing images of tree, cat, dog, lion, etc. When program runs user will see the image and decide in which category this image should go. (Manual classification). Also user can decide what name to give to the particular category.

What libraries I should use so that it can interact with user? I want user to do the manual classification based on image.

Answer (score 2):

You don't even need to write any Python for that, you can do it very simply with [feh](https://linux.die.net/man/1/feh).

Just define your 10 actions, which might be to move or rename a file or add a comment to it, using `--action1` thru `--action9` then press button 0 through 9 for each image when you have decided the class and the corresponding action will be executed.

The *"actions"* are just shell scripts, so you can:

- rename/move files
- delete files
- append filenames to a CSV
- insert record into `sqlite` or other databases
- etc...

Comment: Wow, what a hidden gem..... Thank you!

Comment: Hi Mark. Thanks. I explored the page. I am not sure how to start. Do you have any tutorials on it. Also the question is can I use it in windows? I am sorry if the questions are naïve. I am very new to it. Please bare with me.

Comment: Sorry, I don't use Windows. I understand it has something called *"Windows Subsystem for Linux"* (WSL) which Microsoft added to try and make it useful - so that may be a possibility but I don't know.