# Why does my keypress not work correctly with my own input?

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I am trying to create a script where I can move images from one folder to another with the help of keypress. Using 'c' for clean folder, 'd' for dirty folder, 'v' for vehicle folder and 'q' to quit the program. Additionally, any key to skip the image.

However, there are a few issues that I am facing with the keyboard module and with moving the file.

1. The image window does not close after I move the image to the new folder. It keep openiing to another image after the moving is done.
2. Once I skip an image, two new images open after. I want it to show one image at a time instead of skipping through the first image and then opening two new images simultaneously.

I just cannot understand how the keyboard module is working, I have a feeling it is reading my input more than once but unsure how to fix that.

For example, this is how it shows two images simultaneously, the first image shows when I run the program, if I skip that, it moves onto two images being shown at once, which leads to a total of three images

```
Image: HD17001443_Resolved_Attachment-ezspixoum1-2017-04-0311-47-33.jpg
Press 'c' for Clean, 'v' for Vehicle, 'd' for Dirty, or any other key to skip.
Skipping image... [FIRST IMAGE BEING SKIPPED]
Image: HD17001484_Resolved_Attachment-aehxeiaef3-2017-04-0618-29-26.jpg
Press 'c' for Clean, 'v' for Vehicle, 'd' for Dirty, or any other key to skip.
Skipping image... [SECOND IMAGE BEING SKIPPED IMMEDIATELY]
Image: HD17001491_Resolved_Attachment-nzfvlczcu1-2017-04-0909-39-54.jpg
Press 'c' for Clean, 'v' for Vehicle, 'd' for Dirty, or any other key to skip. [PROCEEDS TO THIRD IMAGE BEING SHOWN]
```

```py
import os
import shutil
import keyboard
from PIL import Image

# Set the path to your source image folder
image_folder = '/path/to/folder/'

# Set the path to the destination folders
clean_folder = '/path/to/folder/'
vehicle_folder = '/path/to/folder/'
dirty_folder = '/path/to/folder/'

# Get the list of image files in the source folder
image_files = sorted(os.listdir(image_folder))

# Initialize the destination folder
dst_folder = None

# Iterate over each image file
for x in image_files:
    # Construct the source and destination paths
    src_path = os.path.join(image_folder, x)

    # Display the image
    image = Image.open(src_path)

    # Prompt for the label
    print(f"Image: {x}")
    print("Press 'c' for Clean, 'v' for Vehicle, 'd' for Dirty, or any other key to skip.")

    image.show()

    # Wait for the user to press a key
    key = keyboard.read_key()
    
    # Determine the destination folder based on the key pressed
    if key == 'c':
        dst_folder = clean_folder
    elif key == 'v':
        dst_folder = vehicle_folder
    elif key == 'd':
        dst_folder = dirty_folder
    elif key == 'q':
        break
    else:
        print("Skipping image...")
        continue

    # Construct the destination path
    dst_path = os.path.join(dst_folder, x)

    # Move the image file to the destination folder
    shutil.move(src_path, dst_folder)

    print(f"Image moved to: {dst_folder}\n")

print("Image labeling completed.")
```

Comment: The `show` function is mainly for debugging purposes. Better use a GUI toolkit like tkinter to show (and hide) images.

Comment: Can I use opencv instead?

Comment: This should work, too.

Comment: You can actually do this very simply with `feh` and without needing any Python, see here https://stackoverflow.com/a/70449081/2836621

Comment: You are showing the image before you make any attempt to ascertain what key was pressed and it is open in another process, so you'll have to find it and kill it. Also why use `keyboard` rather than `input` for the keyboard input, it seems like over kill.